# How Do You Make a Tweet Personal Only To the One You Reply to?

Tags: twitter

When you do a personal reply tweet on another's twitter, it automatically shows up on your own twitter page. What happens if you delete the one on your own page that you don't want out to the world because it was a personal reply on another's page just for them? I mean if it's a person health issue the person does not want out to the world and you reply to it, and then it also shows up on your own twitter page, if you delete it on your own page, will it also delete on the one you replied to where you want it to stay as well?  In other words, how to you make a tweet personal so it's not all over the place and just stays where you tweet it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will delete from everywhere. There is no option to set it for one or two persons. You can make your account private, so whatever you tweet only your approved followers will see.

What are you asking as of now not possible through the tweets. Use [direct message](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14606) feature of Twitter for private conversation.